# Get percentage of values for column grouped by other column - R

Tags: r

If I have a table like,

| Division | Color |
| --- | --- |
| A | Red |
| A | Blue |
| A | Blue |
| A | Yellow |
| B | Blue |
| B | Yellow |
| C | Green |

And I want to find the percentage of colors based on each division, so the output should look like,

| Division | Red | Blue | Yellow | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25.0 | 50.0 | 25.0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 50.0 | 50.0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100.0 |

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Please paste the data into the question using the output of `dput(your_dataframe)` to make the question easily reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
tab <- table(df$Division, df$Color)
100 * tab / rowSums(tab) 
#>     Blue Green Red Yellow
#>   A   50     0  25     25
#>   B   50     0   0     50
#>   C    0   100   0      0
```

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Division = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"
), Color = c("Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Blue", "Yellow", 
"Green")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be another approach using `janitor` and would be nice to learn about:

```
library(janitor)

df %>%
  tabyl(Division, Color) %>%
  adorn_percentages() %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting()

 Division  Blue  Green   Red Yellow
        A 50.0%   0.0% 25.0%  25.0%
        B 50.0%   0.0%  0.0%  50.0%
        C  0.0% 100.0%  0.0%   0.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `proportions`.

```
proportions(table(df), margin=1)*100
#         Color
# Division Blue Green Red Yellow
#        A   50     0  25     25
#        B   50     0   0     50
#        C    0   100   0      0
```